# Create a key bind for Open/Run in SideBarEnhancements

Tags: sublimetext, sidebar

This is a very simple question but I could not find answers for it on google.

**What is the command for Open/Run in Side Bar Enhancements**

Note: This is a question for Sublime Text 3 code editor.

```
[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+alt+b"], "command": "run_existing_window_command", "args":
    {
        "id": "repl_python_run",
        "file": "config/Python/Main.sublime-menu"
    }},
    { "keys": ["f12"], "command": "side_bar_open_in_browser"
    },
    {
        "keys": ["alt+f12"], "command": "side_bar_open/run"
    }
]
```

These are my key bind settings.
I have bound f12 to open in browser.
I want to bind alt+f12 to the open/run command of the side bar enhancements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost have it. The command for **`Open/Run`** is `side_bar_open`. Just remove `/run` from your <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F12</kbd> keybinding and it should work fine.